# Google Analyics _trackEvent not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am attempting to track some outbound links from our site in Google Analytics. I have added the trackEvent code to the link, per Googles documentation (see below). It works in FireFox and Chrome, but not in Internet Explorer (v9). Using Fiddler, I can see that IE isn't generating requests for /__utm.gif.

Any ideas?

```
<a onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'event', 'action', 'label']); popup_url('https://www.google.com/', '_blank', 'width=800,height=600,resizable=1,scrollbars=1,menubar=1,location=1,titlebar=1')" href="#">Google</a>
```

The popup_url is a JavaScript method that wraps window.open and is a user requirement.

Comment: And you've made sure that there are no JavaScript errors?

Comment: Have you tried adding a timeout? Might be a race condition.

Comment: There are no JavaScript errors and I did try adding a timeout. I recently added "_gaq.push(function(){alert('Hello');});" to my initialization code. I get the alert in FireFox and Chrome, but not IE. It appears like the ga.js script isn't initializing properly and executing the command stack.

Comment: @MikeJ - You ever figure this out?

Comment: @d-_-b - Yes, the network team was experimenting and had added google analytics to the blocked site list for my group in group policy. They later removed it, but for some reason it didn't remove it from my PC. Removing it from Internet Settings wasn't enough, I had to go into the registry and remove it there. Once I did that, everything worked correctly.